# Subnet association change in route table of VPC stopped it working

Tags: amazon-web-services, subnet, aws-vpc, routetable

I was working with one of our VPC which was created through CF stack. I manually change the subnet association to the router attached to the VPC after that, the networking seems totally down.

[image: Earlier state of VPC]

[image: Current state of vpc]

I tried to associate all the subnets to route table of VPC again but the network seems down.

Any suggestions, what can we do here?

Answer (score 0):

By default every subnet gets attached to the main route table of the VPC implicitly unless you associate a subnet with a different route table. Check the main route table of the VPC, and which subnets are explicitly associated with non main route table.